# How can I encrypt the passwords of a data source on Tomcat 9 in the context.xml?

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, jdbc, tomcat9

Like the title says, our application has resources in the context.xml that we need to encrypt for security audit purposes. I know Tomcat's FAQ mentions security through obscurity, but we need to have it encrypted for any audit purposes.

Currently a resource in the context.xml looks like this:

```xml
<Resource 
      name="jdbc/OracleDataSource" 
      auth="Container" 
      type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
      driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" 
      url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@ServerName:PORT/NAME" 
      username="APP_USERNAME" 
      password="APP_PASSWORD"
      testWhileIdle="true"
      testOnBorrow="true"
      testOnReturn="false"
      validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
      timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="5000"
      maxTotal="100"
      maxIdle="20"
      minIdle="10"
      maxWaitMillis="10000"
      initialSize="10"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="1800"
      removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true"
      removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true"
      logAbandoned="true"
      minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
/>
```

In our app code we make use of RC4 encoding which the files know to decrypt from the @RC4Encode@XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX format into a clear-text password for other credential uses.

I was hoping to implement this somehow in our context.xml, but I'm unsure how to approach doing that. I saw some previously posts here about BasicDataSourceFactory, but I'm not quite understanding the implementations and when I try to import BasicDataSourceFactory and I get a ClassNotFoundException. I did try to do a variable import in the context.xml however we don't have access the the catalina.properties on the server that our app sits on and we don't have access to the folder structure that it resides in either, which from my understanding killed the possibility of using properties replacement or external XML entities.

If I could figure out how to resolve the DataSourceFactory not found error, I could try to copy some of the "decode" methods used in decoding our passwords back to clear-text and directly call a decode method against the RC4 encoded password and then pass that to the context.xml.

Rough pseudo-code of that DataSourceFactory method:

```java
public class APPDataSourceFactory extends BasicDataSourceFactory {
    private String encrypted_pwd = "@RC4Encode@123,456,789,012,345";
    public void decrypt_pwd(encrypted_pwd,key){
        //Decryption Steps
        return decrypted_pwd;
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding the class not found problem: If `import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory;` throws a compile-time error, then your application needs the DBCP2 library - for example, if you use Maven, see [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2/2.9.0). But mark is as `<scope>provided</scope>`, as these classes are part of Tomcat already (when you deploy your app). This assumes you are actually using DBCP2 (the default Tomcat pool solution). It looks as if you are.

Comment: The only other thing I would add is: "_encrypted for any audit purposes_" - I think an organization is better off spending its time in securing access to its servers, as this does not really provide much security (it may even give a false sense of security). But I understand this is just an opinion - and you may not have any choice, anyway.

Comment: For the record: [Here's the mentioned FAQ article](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Password). It even links to the Vault implementation, implying you don't need to implement anything to achieve a higher level of obfuscation.